# Object type changed from server to client side in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, server-side, next.js, server-side-rendering

In my Next.js application, I'm creating an object in `getInitialProps` function and checking an instance of that object in `constructor`. But it's class type changed while running code on the client-side.

My Class is

```
class TestClass {
    constructor(public name: string, public id: number) {
    }
}
```

And in `getInitialProps` function I'm returning an object of that class

```
static async getInitialProps() {

        const test = new TestType('TestUser', 123);
        return test;
}
```

while checking `instanceof` property in the constructor, it's giving the wrong type on the client-side.

```
constructor(props: AppProps) {
        super(props);    
        console.log('test', props.test instanceof TestClass);
        // true on server side but false on client side.
}
```

So my question is why this is happening and how could I persist correct object type on client-side as well.

Answer (score 0):

`getInitialProps` serializes the returned data from it, and functions can't be serialized.

Mentioned here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps

You'll need to reconstruct the instance once it comes through as a prop on your component.